# How to bypass error with Python Requests "Requests Remote end closed connection without response"

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm making a script to restart my router using Python Requests, I managed to log in the router and I am using the object Session() to keep it logged in as I have to pass another URL to restart the router.

Simple script with only two URLs,
The first URL is a POST method I use this one to log in the router, the second URL is a GET method, this one I'm using to restart the router.

But when the router restarts it ends the connection with my Session()/Script and then the Requests module throws an error.

```
    url = 'http://192.168.1.1/goform/webLogin'

    login_data = {
        "User": "username",
        "Passwd": "password"
    }

    ses = requests.Session()

    ses.post(url, data = login_data)


    ses.get('http://192.168.1.1/goform/reboot')
```

it should restart the router and end the script without errors, it indeed restarts the router, but I am getting this error

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))

How do I fix that? i thought about using try/except and ignore this but I am not sure if it's the best way to fix it.

Comment: Instead of "ignoring" the error you can just make your own warning message inside your except block using the `warnings` module.
`warnings.warn("Connection aborted")`

Comment: That exception is telling you "The router is a jerk! It did not even say goodbye". You can safely ignore it. The only way to fix it would be to upgrade the firmware of your router with something that does not act like a jerk when rebooting and properly says goodbye to the HTTP requests. In other words: you can just catch the exception and ignore it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to catch the exception as I am planning to keep coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal as the router is shutting down, you should expect this behavior from your router. The exception is the confirmation of the script working well. I would try to catch the exception if I need to continue doing something else in the script

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna keep coding then and catch this error.